# Mapping property of $p$-Sylow groups of profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian profinite groups. Then we have the Sylow group decomposition
$$G\cong \prod_p G_p.$$
In the case of finite groups, we have $ \prod_p G_p\cong \bigoplus_p G_p$ and thus
$$\text{Hom}\left( \prod_p G_p,T\right)\cong \text{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_p G_p, T\right)\cong \prod_p \text{Hom}\left(G_p,T\right).$$
In the profinite case, we have $ \prod_p G_p\ncong\bigoplus_p G_p$ and thus in general we don't know the maps out of $\prod_p G_p.$ My question is if there exists some nice class of topological groups $T$ such that
$$\text{Hom}\left( \prod_p G_p,T\right)\overset{?}{\cong} \prod_p \text{Hom}\left(G_p,T\right).$$
For instance, using the injective map $\bigoplus_p G_p\rightarrow  \prod_p G_p$, for injective topological groups we have a surjection $\text{Hom}\left( \prod_p G_p,T\right)\rightarrow \text{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_p G_p, T\right).$ Is there a good additional condition making this map injective?

Comment: If $T$ is a compact abelian group and Hom refers to continuous group homomorphisms, this is an isomorphism.

Comment: @YCor What is the argument in that case?

Comment: @YCor: really? That doesn't seem right. If, say, $T = S^1$ then what I'd expect (using that Pontryagin duality is an equivalence of categories) is $\text{Hom}(\prod G_p, S^1) \cong \oplus_p \text{Hom}(G_p, S^1)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks, I was not careful. I should have said, for $T$ a *profinite* abelian group.